# Toggle Switch correctly removes css class on false but doesn't put the class back on when true

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-5

Using a Bootstrap5 toggle switch (which is basically just a checkbox) to toggle on and off lines in a grid.  I have it set up so if the toggle is true then add the class which adds lines for the grid and if it's false then remove class and the lines.  When I toggle off the class that holds the style for the line gets removed correctly but when I toggle on then the class doesn't come back and toggle the lines on.  I am also using a `forEach()` to loop through all the divs.

I have `console.log` within and they fire for each toggle so I am not sure what I am missing.  Here is the code

JS

```
let gridToggleSwitch = document.querySelector("#gridToggle")

gridToggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', () => {

    let boxList = document.querySelectorAll('.box')

    let toggleChoice = gridToggleSwitch.checked

    if(toggleChoice == true) {
        console.log("LINES")

        boxList.forEach((e) => {
            console.log(e)

            e.classList.add('box')
        })

    } else if (toggleChoice == false) {
        console.log('NO LINES')

        boxList.forEach((e) => {
            console.log(e)

            e.classList.remove('box')
        })

    } else {
        console.log('woops')
    }

})
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: When you remove the `box` class, the query selector doesn't find anything. You should use a different class to find all the boxes you want to toggle.

Comment: Or if the list of boxes doesn't change dynamically, set `boxList` outside of the event listener, before you've removed the class.

Comment: aside, while it's probably OK here, using `== true` or `== false` is asking for trouble. Try `if (toggleChoice) {...} else {...}` instead.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

since the grid can change dynamically I needed to also dynamically add an ID to the divs for the grid and instead of using the forEach() for the classes I looped through the ID and added/removed the border style